# Deploying a dockerfile to AWS Fargate (Building docker images on AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-fargate

I have the end goal of deploying a docker container on AWS Fargate. As it happens, my dockerfile has no local dependencies and my upload connection is very slow, thus I want to build it in the cloud. What would be the easiest way to build the image on AWS? Creating an EC2 Linux instance, installing docker and aws-cli in it, building the image then uploading to AWS ECR, if that's possible?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is by using [AWS CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/) - it will do everything for you, even push it to `AWS ECR`.

Basic instructions: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html)

Comment: This is not part of a CI/CD pipeline; but a one-time task

Comment: @tsorn even for one-time task, it's easiest thing, just point to proper Dockerfile and build it.